# cookie not setting when variable is used for cookie name

Tags: php, cookies

On my server when using the code:

```
<?php
$expire=time()+60*60*24*360;

$cookie_name = 'user';
$cookie_value = "John";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $expire, "/");

$cookie_value = "Jane";
setcookie('userb', $cookie_value, $expire, "/");

print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

The first cookie does not set, but the second one does. For some reason it appears that using a variable to identify the cookie name causes it not to set.
This problem does NOT occur on my localhost (everything works as expected). So I'm not even really sure where to begin.

Comment: Cookies created with `setcookie` will only show up in `$_COOKIE` in the **next** request.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it was because I had a:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

before the `<?php`
Which for some reason works fine locally, but not on my server. Any suggestions?

Comment: That would have to break **all** headers **ever**... could it be that `output_buffering` is turned on in your php.ini?

Comment: That was it. output_buffering was turned off on my server. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: To elaborate on Siguza's correct answer: A HTTP response is made out of a `header` and a `body`. The server has to fully sent `header` before sending `body` can be started. Strings like `<!DOCTYPE html>` go into the `body`. If you start outputting the `body`, PHP will implicitly send the `header` for you. So after you started outputting something into `body` you can't manipulate the `header` anymore - it has already been sent. If you have `output_buffering` turned on, writes to `body` will be buffered to a certain threshold in which you could, but **should not** manipulate the `header`.

Comment: That's weird. I was using the tutorial from w3schools ( http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_cookie1 ). So that tutorial won't work with output buffering off?

Answer (score 0):

change the parameter of setcookie function and then try.
eg.

```
$expire=time()+60*60*24*360;
$cookie_name = 'user';
$cookie_value = "John";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $expire, "/");

$cookie_value1 = "Jane";
setcookie('userb', $cookie_value1, $expire, "/");

print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Answer (score -1):

You cant use more than 1 setcookie function.

```
<?php
$expire=time()+60*60*24*360;
$cookie_name = 'user';
$cookie_value = "John";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $expire, "/");
//$cookie_value = "Jane";
//setcookie('userb', $cookie_value, $expire, "/");
print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```